# Running two timers simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

I have two timers, each running a different TimerTask. I want  timerTask1 to run every 5 seconds, while timerTask2 should run ever 20 seconds.

```
Timer timerPush = new Timer("RESTtimer");//create a new Timer
Timer timerPoll = new Timer("POLLTimer");//create a new Timer

timerPush.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask1, 0, 5000);
timerPoll.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, 0, 20000);
```

However, I am only seeing timerTask1 being executed. Could someone explain what is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Are timerTask1 and timerTask2 accidentally referring to the same task?

Comment: Your code works as expected when executed using Oracle Java 7 on Windows 7.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have shared, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/yxda1V). The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove: That would cause an exception.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. The error was elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution I can think of is, you can spawn two threads one for each timer.
First thread will do

```
  timerPush.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask1, 0, 5000);
```

and other will do

```
  timerPoll.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask2, 0, 20000);
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening right now? Doesn't TimerTask already run on its own thread?